# How can I send custom messeges to an alarm service when the alarm is triggered?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Here I am facing the problem with Alarm, In my app I need alarm service in my app to remind the user to do his task. The task, time, and Dates are stored in the database. When the time, date reached then the alarm app will show a pop up message with a text which we stored in the database while adding a alarm. How can I pass the text message which is stored in tne database as notification in my AlarmService class. But I am unable to pass aa text to ShowNotifiction() (which i created). How can I pass a text to my ClaramService..

thanks,
ravi

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps extend the AlarmService class and in your subclass have methods to set the notification text.

What class did you create a ShowNotification() method in?